# how to efficiently monitor system stat using vmstat?

Tags: monitoring, vmstat

Am getting the real-time memory stats from `vmstat` command. I did this using following steps:

```
$ nohup vmstat 60 > vmstatrecord.app &
```

the command executes in background and writes the log to the file `vmstatrecord.app`. When i see use the command

```
$ ps -A | grep stat
```

I could see the vmstat running in the background and i could also access the log using tail command as:

```
$ tail -f vmstatrecord.app
```

the file updates every 60sec interval.

Now my question is :process continues to write to the file so what will happen if i leave for days ?

Assumption: If the process writes the file forever **am afraid that the file size might grow too large**

If my assumption is correct and my steps are inefficient. Is there any alternatives to achieve what am trying to achieve from my above steps ?

Already Asked it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282889/how-to-efficiently-monitor-system-stat-using-vmstat)

Comment: why not use sysstat(sar)?

Comment: I would also suggest ot use dedicated software like atop, sysstat, mrtg(snmp), or proprietary solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `vmstat` to build this sort of thing is possible, but you will get a lot more results for our effort by configuring something like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) or cacti.  All of the stats you are getting from `vmstat` plus `iostat` plus more will get turned into pretty graphs.  Munin and other similar tools use RRD to avoid having data fill up your drive.